# Is there a way to skip the saving before Wonder Trade?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I enjoy using Wonder Trade to get rid of Masuda Method leftovers and to work on the Pokedex. But, it takes a long time because I must save before each trade. Is there a way to activate Wonder Trade without saving, or because of trading, it is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to disable saving before Wonder Trade. It is done most likely to prevent duplicating pokemon. It also assists the player so that if the system dies, data is not lost.

Comment: That does not work. I tried setting it to that, but it still asks before each Wonder Trade.

Comment: You are right, I just tried it and it does not disable forced saving before trading. I changed my answer to reflect this. 
Not sure why saving bothers you so much though, considering it's almost instant (unlike previous gen games).

Comment: It's the worst as like @ShadowZorgon says, if you've got 2-3 boxes of breeding rejects you want to Wondertrade, you've got to save after every one

Comment: @Chippies I know it is not that long, but if I can save any amount of time saved can speed it up.

Comment: Aah, Nintendo UI. If Nintendo were to design a hallway, they would add a door every 5 feet. (see also; mulching berries.)